# CDP extension ASN.1 tag

Tags: asn.1

I'm trying to understand ASN.1 format used in CDP Extension in x509 certificate.

When reading the cert from google, I see these code related:

`30 26 30 24 a0 22 a0 20 86 1e (url start)`

according to http://rcardon.free.fr/websign/download/api-x509-ext/be/cardon/asn1/x509/extensions/CRLDistributionPoints.html and http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/iaik_jce/current/iaik/asn1/structures/GeneralNames.html, the GeneralNames should be a SEQUENCE of GeneralName. Why there is a 86 directly without another 30?

Thanks a lot.

Update: 
And, I know it may be not correct in grammar, if there is only one DistributionPoint with one DistributionPointName-Url(*1), DistributionPointName-nameRelativeToCRLIssuer(*2), a reason with all 0(*3), and 2 cRLIssuer-DNSName(*4 and *5), the packet should be:

```
  30 len --DistributionPoint
    a0 len --DistributionPointName for distributionPoint
      a0 len --GeneralNames for fullName
        86 len --IA5String for uniformResourceIdentifier
        (*1) data here
      a1 len --RelativeDistinguishedName for nameRelativeToCRLIssuer  (edited)
        (*2) data here
    81 03 --Reason
      07 00 00 --BITSTRING of Reason (*3)
    a2 len --GeneralNames for cRLIssuer
      82 len --IA5String for dNSName
        (*4) data here
      82 len --IA5String for dNSName
        (*5) data here
```

Am I right?

Comment: `07 00 00 --BITSTRING of Reason (*3)` what's that? If you want to set to zero, then you completely omit `reasons` field. It is optional. When presented (for example, for `keyCompromise` and `caCompromise` reasons), it should be `81 02 05 60`. And `RelativeDistinguishedName` is constructed, so tag will be `a1`, not `81`. The rest seems ok for me.

Comment: @Crypt32 I thought the first byte in BIT STRING should be the 'UNUSED BITS' count.

Comment: what reasons you want to assert?

Comment: To understand the ASN1 format.

Comment: You can't explain ASN.1 in single thread, it is more complex. If you do not assert any bit, then all 8 bits are unused. BIT_STRING allows up to 7 unused bits, so `03 03 07 00 00` is invalid BIT_STRING value. It should be `03 01 00` (in primitive form), or (better) omitted at all. I would recommend to read this great brief intro into ASN.1: http://luca.ntop.org/Teaching/Appunti/asn1.html

Comment: and, please, try to limit your thread only to one question. Otherwise, it is easy to go to offtopic and outside the scope of original question. If you have more questions, try to search existing threads or start a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to analyze provided octets? You ask for missing SEQUENCE, but do not ask for extra `a0` tag around `86` tag. If you would, you could figure out what is going on.

The binary encoding of your CDP extension value looks ok. 0x86 is general name CHOICE of `uniformResourceLocator` field. If you split down your binary string into pieces you will get the following mapping (assuming implicit tagging mode, as per RFC 5280):

- 30 26 -- maps to `CRLDistributionPoints`
- 30 24 -- maps to `DistributionPoint`
- a0 22 -- maps to `DistributionPointName` (it is OPTIONAL field, thus uses implicit tagging)
- a0 20 -- maps to `GeneralNames` (it is a CHOICE value, thus uses implicit tagging)
- 86 1e -- maps to `uniformResourceIdentifier` field of `IA5String` type. It is CHOICE value, this uses implicit tagging.

It seems you are confused with tags. `GeneralName` type indeed is `SEQUENCE`, but in a given context it is used within a CHOICE, so it is implicitly tagged: SEQUENCE tag is replaced with a corresponding `CONTEXT_SPECIFIC` tag [0].

**Update:**

When ASN module contains CHOICE, OPTIONAL, DEFAULT keywords, they are using CONTEXT_SPECIFIC class which has base tag number 0x80. Selectors are specified in square brackets. In these cases, you do (when module defaults to implicit tags, like in our case): CONTEXT_SPECIFIC class (0x80) + CONSTRUCTED BIT (0x32) from original type + Selector number in square brackets.

For example, optional SEQUENCE with selector 0 will result in 0x80 + 0x20 + 0 = 0xa0. CHOICE [6] IA5String will result in 0x80 + 0x0 (CONSTRUCTED bit is 0) + 0x6 = 0x86.

When module defaults to explicit tags or there is EXPLICIT keywor, then original type is not changed (SEQUENCE remains SEQUENCE), instead it is encoded as nested type for CONSTRUCTED CONTEXT_SPECIFIC.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I get you right, 1:
A0 means select the choice 0 and the data struct following is context specified and constructed, but not mean the following byte should describe the struct itself. And 2: If there is more than one GeneralName nodes, all url for example, in the same GeneralNames node, there will be multiple "86 len data" combined directly without any other code between each pair of them. Am I right?

Comment: If I get you right, the second 30 is required because DistributionPoint is a sequence may contains multiple sub nodes. No more 30 between A0 and 86 because the GeneralName is a choice which contains one but only node.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any problem in my update of question?

Comment: And, please see the OtherName in GeneralNames. It is a SEQUENCE but only the 2nd node has a [0]. So the data should be ```06 len OID [80] len value``` ?