# ASN.1 BitString encoding for CRLDistributionPoints.ReasonFlags

Tags: asn.1

@Crypt32 says: `for keyCompromise and caCompromise reasons, it should be 81 02 05 60` -- (comment after question [CDP extension ASN.1 tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61817332/cdp-extension-asn-1-tag)).

`05 60 is: 00000101 01100000`

```
ReasonFlags ::= BIT STRING {
    unused                  (0),
    keyCompromise           (1),
    cACompromise            (2),
    affiliationChanged      (3),
    superseded              (4),
    cessationOfOperation    (5),
    certificateHold         (6),
    privilegeWithdrawn      (7),
    aACompromise            (8) }
```

Why the keyCompromise+cACompromise is encoded into 05 60? Thanks.

Update: In Windows, 05 60 is decoded as cessationOfOperation (5)

[image]

Comment: keep in mind that leading `05` is a number of unused bits. Only `60` denotes actual value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`05` is unused bit count. It is a part of BIT_STRING. `60` (all octets are presented in hex) is bit string value. BIT_STRING is a long string of bits. Bits are indexed in LTR direction. Minimum transfer unit is byte, so every bit string length is multiple of 8 bits. If the length of actual bit string is divided by 8 with remainder, remainder denotes unused bits. Unused bits is a number of zero bits after last `1` till the end of byte. If all 8 bits on the right side are unused, then zero byte is not encoded.

Bit index maps 1:1 to bit numbers in parenthesis in ASN.1 module. ASN.1 module defines 9 bits that require 2 bytes to encode:

[image]

Since all bits in 2nd byte are zero, this byte is not encoded:

[image]

You see that bits (1) and (2) are set to `1`, this maps to a bitwise OR combination of enabled `keyCompromise` and `cACompromise` flags. The rest bits are zero till the end of byte, thus are not used. If we count them, we get 5 unused bits and encoded value will look as this:

```
03 02 05 60
```

where:

- 03 -- tag identifier
- 02 -- tag length
- 05 -- unused bits cound
- 60 -- encoded value

What if you include `aACompromise` bit? This bit requires second byte:

[image]

All the rest of bits (after 9th bit) are zero, thus they are unused (exactly 7 bits). So encoding for this setting is:

```
03 03 07 60 80
```

where:

- 03 -- tag identifier
- 03 -- tag length
- 07 -- unused bits count
- 60 80 -- encoded value

IDK if I had explained it good enough, I did all my best.

Comment: Sorry, but Windows says that 05 60 is ```Cessation of Operation```.
In Certificate view, a cert with 05 60 displays as  ```CRL Reason=Cessation of Operation (05 60)```

Comment: The encoding is invalid. It should be `81 02 05 60`, without `03`.

Comment: Again: `03 02 05 60` is encoding in primitive form. In the case of implicit tagging, you replace `03` tag with optional selector (OPTIONAL [1]): `81` and get `81 02 05 60`.

Comment: Great explanation. @Crypt32, are there any official spec about how to parse a BitString, can you point me about it? Thanks.

Comment: ITU-T X.690 and RFC5280.